# EntityFramework issue executing a query after migrate from Sql Server to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Ey, recently i have migrated a database from SQL Server to MySQL, installed the MySql.Data 6.10.6 and MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.11, updated the ADO Model from Mysql to regenerate all the *.cs's and the most of the code runs fine but im having an error when i try to execute this query:

```
List<int> ids = this.db.functions
              .Where(f => f.active == true
                     && f.actions
                       .Where(af => af.types.name == 'TYPE1'
                              && af.groups
                                 .Where(g => g.users
                                    .Where(u => u.uname == 'user1')
                                    .Count() > 0
                        )
                        .Count() > 0
               )
               .Count() > 0

        )
        .Select(f => f.mod.id)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

I get this error:

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
Unknown column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause'
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. 
Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del 
error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown 
column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause'
```

And this is the log from EF building the query, i think here comes the problem, EF is not building the query fine :(

```
Opened connection at 17/04/2018 12:40:02 +02:00
SELECT
`Distinct1`.`m_xref`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
`Project5`.`m_xref`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`m_xref`, 
`Extent1`.`active_b`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM (SELECT
`Project1`.`name`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM (SELECT
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `user_group_user` AS `Extent5` INNER JOIN `user` AS `Extent6` ON 
`Extent6`.`id` = `Extent5`.`user_xref`
WHERE (`Project2`.`group_xref` = `Extent5`.`group_xref`) AND     
(`Extent6`.`uname`     = @p__linq__0)) AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent4`.`group_xref`
FROM `p_group_fun` AS `Extent4`
 WHERE (`Project1`.`fun_xref` = `Extent4`.`fun_xref`) AND     
(`Project1`.`action_xref` = `Extent4`.`action_xref`)) AS `Project2`) AS     
`Project3`
 WHERE `Project3`.`C1` > 0) AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent2`.`fun_xref`, 
`Extent2`.`action_xref`, 
`Extent3`.`name`
FROM `actions_fun` AS `Extent2` INNER JOIN `types` AS `Extent3` ON     
`Extent2`.`action_xref` = `Extent3`.`id`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`id` = `Extent2`.`fun_xref`) AS `Project1`) AS `Project4`
 WHERE (@gp1 = `Project4`.`name`) AND (`Project4`.`C1` > 0)) AS `C1`
FROM `functions` AS `Extent1`) AS `Project5`
 WHERE (1 = `Project5`.`active_b`) AND (`Project5`.`C1` > 0)) AS `Distinct1`
-- p__linq__0: 'user1' (Type = String, Size = 7)
-- @gp1: 'TYPE1' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 7)
-- Executing at 17/04/2018 12:40:03 +02:00
-- Failed in 3 ms with error: Unknown column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause'

Closed connection at 17/04/2018 12:40:03 +02:00
```

Comment: Please add the error message as text, not image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your database tables are not updated as in the models,you need to update the database accordingly ,as MySql is not finding the Id which you are using in your query.

Comment: I regenerated the ADO model from MySQL :(

Answer (score 0):

When you changed your DB, you forgot to rebuild every column, that's what the error is saying, take care of it